# python - passing variables across methods and classes

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I have some code that generically resembles the following:

```
class ABC(Parent):
    def func1(self, **kwargs)
        start_time = time.time()
        ...
        ...
    return stuff

class XYZ(Parent):
    def func2(self, **kwargs)
        ...
        ...
        a = time.time() - start_time           
    return other_stuff
```

I'm looking for the absolute simplest way to use the variable `start_time` defined in `func1` of class ABC inside of `func2` within class XYZ.

Note: This code is very generic and the actual code I'm working with is much, much more complicated. Other answers I've found have mentioned defining `start_time` outside of either class and then passing them in, OR they involve changing arguments. I cannot do this. My `start_time` needs to be defined exactly here and nowhere else, and I cannot change my arguments for either `func1` or `func2`.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: your arguments are `**kwargs`, you can pass anything.

Comment: You have to pass the instance of  `ABC` to the instance of `XYZ`.

Comment: @Daniel what is the syntax for this? I'm very new to Python.

Comment: If you cannot change anything, then you cannot solve your problem. _Other answers_ seem to have very good suggestions. A variable is declared within a function if it is not needed outside. Otherwise it belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to solve your problem in a method that isn't going to be messy. Essentially, you will need to use a variable outside both of your functions. I think your best option is to use python's `global` keyword:

```
class ABC(Parent):
    def func1(self, **kwargs):
        global start_time
        start_time = time.time()

        return stuff

class XYZ(Parent):
    def func2(self, **kwargs):
        global start_time
        a = time.time() - start_time

        return other_stuff
```

The use of `global` here allows you to avoid defining your variable outside of your function.

Comment: Best to avoid polluting the global namespace with `global`s when you could simply pass around class instances and access `start_time` via `ABC.start_time`

Comment: I agree, but the original question stated that there could be no arguments passed.

Comment: But no arguments need to be passed? Instance attributes will do.

Comment: If you want to use instances of each class independently, you will need to pass arguments. By their statement: "My start_time needs to be defined exactly here and nowhere else, and I cannot change my arguments for either func1 or func2." It sounds like that is what they are looking for

Comment: Would you say I'm passing arguments in my answer? (none of the methods take any arguments except `self`)

Comment: No, but you are assuming that class `XYZ` is dependent on `ABC` and `ABC` is not dependent on `XYZ`. From the original question, there is no way to tell if that is possible in his code.

Comment: The OP wants to _"(...) use the variable start_time defined in func1 of class ABC inside of func2 within class XYZ"_ I understand that as a "one-way" dependency. If you need to pass values in both directions, it might make sense to create a third class that instantiates both `ABC` and `XYZ` instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways of doing it. Here's one that avoids `global` by making `start_time` an instance variable/attribute of `ABC` and instantiating `ABC` within `XYZ`. I think this is also what the user @Daniel was hinting at in the comment *"You have to pass the instance of ABC to the instance of XYZ"*.

```
import time


class Parent:
    pass


class ABC(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None

    def func1(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()


class XYZ(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = ABC()

    def func2(self):
        self.abc.func1()
        return time.time() - self.abc.start_time           


xyz = XYZ()
print(xyz.func2())
```

Python3.5 output:

```
>>> xyz = XYZ()
>>> print(xyz.func2())
9.5367431640625e-07
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make `start_time` a class attribute in `Parent`.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None

class ABC(Parent):
    def func1(self, **kwargs)
        self.start_time = time.time()
        ...
        ...
    return stuff

class XYZ(Parent):
    def func2(self, **kwargs)
        ...
        ...
        a = time.time() - self.start_time           
    return other_stuff
```

Comment: `start_time` is a independent variable each instance.